# How to avoid repeated definition of variables

Tags: android

I've got a simple app which is essentially a tabbed layout with a fragment for each tab. Each of these fragments have several user input fields which I validate the input using regex patterns.

Currently I define the regex patterns in the fragment file itself, but this means I’ve got duplicated code across the fragments which I know is not good practice.

What would be considered best-practice for storing this sort of variable? Should I create a separate class and just define them as static variables in there? Something like this:

```java
public class GlobalVars {
    public static Pattern validTime = Pattern.compile(“(?:[01]...);
    public static Pattern validName = Pattern.compile(“(?:[a-z]...);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it would be appropriate to move something like this out to a `Constants` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A utils class with static methods may best suit your needs:

```
class StringUtils {

    private static final Pattern validTime = Pattern.compile(“(?:[01]...);
    private static final Pattern validName = Pattern.compile(“(?:[a-z]...);

    public static boolean isValidTime(String time) {
        return validTime.matcher(time).matches()
    }
    public static boolean isValidName(String name) {
        return validName.matcher(name).matches()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do multiple classes need to know these very specific patterns?  Sounds like the behavior that needs to know about them should be refactored into helper functions, and then can exist in just one place.  Something like

```
class Validator {
    public static boolean isValidTime(String time) {
        //check if time is valid using pattern
    }
    public static boolean isValidName(String name) {
        //check name
    }
}
```